Expansion of a variadic template inside an if statement
I tried to write a function to check that a 'http::verb' is any of 'allowed' using a variadic template. Here is the code that I initially wrote using examples online:
template<typename... Args>
void CheckMethod(const http::verb& received, const Args&... allowed) const {
    if((received != allowed) && ...) {
        throw ApiError("method is not allowed")
    }
}

However, this doesn't compile and results in an error:
error: expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'allowed'
  386 |                 if((received != allowed) && ... ) {
      |                    ^            ~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

What fixed it was another set of parentheses:
if( ((received != allowed) && ...) )

The questions I used for reference:
Variadic macro for checking if variable equals one of variadic arguments
Test if all elements are equal with C++17 fold-expression
So, why doesn't it work without the extra parentheses? Is it to do with how the expression is unpacked?
upd: I found out that a supposedly better way is to write
if(((received != allowed) && ...) == false) {

Can somebody please explain how and why this is better (if it is at all)?

Whether the == false version is wrong or not depends on what the "then" branch says; if it is the throw statement as in the other version, the == false version is wrong, isn't it?

This is the way fold expressions work, you need to put the parentheses. Adding a test ==false may be a little bit clearer but this is mostly a matter of taste.

@j6t Yes, the == false flips the if if it is made as shown now. Whether you want if (test()) or if (test() == true) - or if (!test()) or if (test() == false) is mostly a matter of style and taste, but the two versions shown in the question right now are inverted.

Fold expressions need a separate pair of paranteces; that's part of the syntax. So you need 3 pairs of paranteces: one for if, one for the fold expression, and one more for the folded expression.

You ask:

why doesn't it work without the extra parentheses?

And the boring answer is that that is just how the grammar for C++ works.
If you look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if you will see that a simple if statement (if we remove the optional stuff) is:
if ( condition ) statement-true

So, if (1==2) doStuff(); is valid, but if 1==2 doStuff(); is not; the () are missing.
Then you can look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold and see that a simple fold expression is:
( pack op ... )
This means that once again the () are a non-optional part of the grammar. So if you want to put this fold expression as the condition for an if, then it just has to go: if (( pack op ...)) statement-true because the inner () are a non-optional part of the fold, and the outer ones are a non-optional part of the if.
